# Simple Encrypt and Decrypt TXT Files [C++]

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to create some kind of encrypt and decrypt texts by changing the characters. 
here is my code:

```
string row;
string fileName = "NULL";

const string encrypt[63] = { "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                        "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                        "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9" " " };
const string decrypt[63] = { "!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","|","~","`",":", "/", "<", ">", ".",
                        "q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m",
                        "Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J" };

printf("Would you like to read or write file ?");
cin >> row;

printf("What the Name of the File?");
cin >> fileName;

if (row._Equal("write") || row._Equal("Write"))
{
    ofstream file(fileName + ".txt");
    string text;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        printf("What Text You Like To Encrypt?");
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, text);

        string nText;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {
            int num = NULL;
            num = text.find(text.find(encrypt[i]));
            if (num != NULL) {
                nText.append(decrypt[num]);
            }
            num = NULL;
        }

        file << nText;
        file.close();
    }
}

else if (row._Equal("read") || row._Equal("Read"))
{
    string text;
    ifstream file(fileName + ".txt");

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        string nText;

        while (getline(file, text))
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
            {
                //Almost Same with Encrypt.
            }
        }

        printf("\nDecrypted File: %s \n", text.c_str());

        file.close();
    }

}
```

now I know that the For loop ( content of the for loop ) is my problem.
at the beginning, i tried to replace chars but I had problems with Replace function so I tried to create a new string to append my encrypt/decrypt.

but I keep getting Debug Error which saying 'abort() has been called'.
I don't know how to fix it ...
thanks for help.

Comment: is `._Equal` a member of `std::string`?

Comment: Don't use `NULL` for numbers.

Comment: Print the value of `num` when you're "successful" and compare to what you expect it to be.

Comment: And don't use internal implementation functions like `_Equal`. Use `==`.

Comment: You need to use a debugger and step through the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it work like this:

```
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 63; j++)
                {
                    if (text[i] == encrypt[j])
                    {
                        nText += decrypt[j];
                    }
                }
        }
```